# How to use scipy.integrate.fixed_quad for computing many integrals at once?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, array-broadcasting

Given a function `func(x,y,z)`, I want to provide a function

```
def integral_over_z(func,x,y,zmin=0,zmax=1,n=16):
    lambda_func = z,x,y: ???
    return scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(lambda_func,a=zmin,b=zmax,args=(x,y),n=n)
```

that computes its integral over `z` for user provided `(x,y)` inputs using `scipy.integrate.fixed_quad`. The input `(x,y)` can be each be a single float or an array of floats (when both are arrays, their shapes are identical).

[`scipy.integrate.fixed_quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.fixed_quad.html#scipy.integrate.fixed_quad) supports integrating vector-valued functions. To this end, the function `func` must return a corresponding array of higher dimension: "If integrating a vector-valued function, the returned array must have shape `(..., len(x))`" (from the docs).

My question therefore is how to generate the corresponding output array of the `lambda_func` (which may be implemented using a special-purpose `class`).

EDIT: to help understand my question, here is an implementation that works, but is not vectorized over `z` (and hence doesn't use `scipy.integrate.fixed_quad`).

```
def integral_over_z(func,x,y,zmin,zmax,n=16):
    z,w = scipy.special.roots_legendre(n)
    dz = 0.5*(zmax-zmin)
    z = zmin + (np.real(z)+1) * dz
    w = np.real(w) * dz
    result = w[0] * func(x,y,z[0])
    for i in range(1,len(z)):
        result += w[i] * func(x,y,z[i])
    return result
```

The problem is: how to vectorize it, such that it works for any valid input (`x` and/or `y` floats or arrays).

ANOTHER EDIT:
For the implementation via `scipy.integrate.fixed_quad`, the integrand function must take a 1D array of `z` of shape `(nz)`. The inputs `x` and `y` must broadcast together, when the broadcasted shape of them could be anything, say `(n0,n1,..,nk)` Then the return from `func` must have shape `(n0,n1,..,nk,nz)` -- how to I generated that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems as a vector valued function the vector values must be in the 0th dimension, and the integration arguments (in your case `z`) must come last (that what they mean with `(..., len(x))`, their `x` is your `z`), I think this comes from the broadcasting rules. Following example worked fine for me - the key here is that `x` and `y` must have the right shape for the broadcasting to work

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
def integral_over_z(func,x,y,n=16):
    lambda_func = lambda z, x, y: func(x[..., None],y[..., None],z)  # the last dimension of (x,y) needs to be size 1, but you can have as many leading dimensions as you want
    return scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(lambda_func,a=0,b=1,args=(x,y),n=n)
func = lambda x,y,z: 1 + 0*x + 0*y + 0*z  # make sure that the output has the right (broadcast) shape
x = np.zeros((5,))
y =  np.arange(5)
print(integral_over_z(func, x, y, 2))
```

Comment: So when `y, z` arguments are shape (m,1), and `x` is (n,), the function should return a (m,n) array.  The integral will be (m,) shape.  More generally it works as long as `x,y,z` broadcast together, returning a (p,q,...,n) shape.

Comment: your *# make sure that the output has the right (broadcast) shape* is obviously the important part. You don't solve this problem *inside* `integral_over_z`, but outside, and hence fail to answer my question, unfortunately.

Comment: @Walter It wasn't clear for me from your question, but it is straightforward to solve that problem by moving the creation of the dummy dimension inside the function, I'll change the code accordingly!

Comment: I think that was pretty clear from my question.

Answer (score 0):

After the (incomplete) answer by *flawr* and reading about `numpy` broadcasting, I found a solution. I'd be happy to learn whether this can still be improved and/or if this is really correct, i.e. works for any valid input (it does for my tests sofar).

The important point is to adapt the shapes of `x` and `y` such that

- `func(x,y,z)` works just fine, i.e. `x`, `y`, and `z` are jointly broadcastable;
- after summing the output of `func` over the last (`z`) dimension, the result has the joint broadcasted shape of `x` and `y`.

Here is my solution:

```
def integral_over_z(func,x,y,zmin=0,zmax=1,n=16):
    xe = x
    ye = y
    if type(xe) is np.ndarray or type(ye) is np.ndarray:
        xe,ye = np.broadcast_arrays(x,y)   # replace x,y by their joint broadcast
        xe = np.expand_dims(xe, xe.ndim)   # expand by an extra dimension for z
        ye = np.expand_dims(ye, ye.ndim)   # expand by an extra dimension for z
    return scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(lambda z : func(xe,ye,z), a=zmin, b=zmax, n=n)
```